# Save LaTeX (or MathML) and plot from matplotlib as 1 image

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, mathml

I'm generating differential equations and their corresponding plots for a web app, and would like to be able to send everything over as one image. How can I do this?

It seems that adding the LaTeX to the plot itself would be difficult to automate, so I'm thinking I might have to separately generate an image of the rendered LaTeX (or MathML, I already have functions to output both representations) and then combine that with the image of the plot. Any method is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`PyPDF2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2/1.24):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

myFiles = ['file1.pdf','file2.pdf']

merger = PdfFileMerger()
for filename in myFiles:
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename, 'rb')))

merger.write("output.pdf")
```

**PS:** You may need to `pip install pypdf2` if you already don't have it.